# What does ECHO + semicolon do in a bat file

Tags: batch-file

I am have been looking some sample bat file code and they used `echo;%variable%`. My question is what does the addition of the semicolon do? I made a test .cmd file with different echos the only thing I noticed was that it counts as a space as in

```
echo; HI
```

is the same as

```
echo  Hi
```

(Note the two spaces before `Hi`).

They both echo  `Hi` (with one space in front of the word Hi).

So what does the `;` accomplish? I could not find any information on it.

Thanks,

Mack

Comment: take a look at [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&p=4554#p4554)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `;` echos a blank line if the variable is empty instead of saying `ECHO is off`. It is the same as using a period (`ECHO.%variable%`).